# I can't get the json array using httpget in angular

Tags: angular, http, get

I would like to retrieve an Json array  with an http get request on a local address but I can't. here is my code where I try to get the Json array

```
export class SecondPageComponent{

data = [] as  any;  

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,private http: HttpClient) { 

this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:5000/Client/GetAllWorkUs').subscribe(response =>{ 
  this.data = response;
  console.log(response);
});

}
}
```

that's what I see when I go to the address in a browser,

[browserImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tdqk.png)

if you can give me some solution that would be great.

I thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like you are getting a JSON array. What do you mean you need it as a JSON array?

Comment: I would like to be able to do data.ip and data.status and display them on mat-table

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a JSON array as response. You need to access the objects using the array index.

```js
this.data[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

use `console.table(response)` to view response as a json table.

Otherwise use `JSON.parse(response)` if you received JSON as a string.

Or else you have to modify your service request to send json only..

Like if it's python flask you can use `jsonify({'data':data})`